# from a bool function return false inside a loop in C#

Tags: c#

I was recently told that it is a bad practise to return false from inside a loop, though it might not actually be called more than once. Is it better to have a secondary flag to actually break out of the functions?

```
foo()
{
  if(bar)
    //somecode
  else
    //some other code
}
private static bool bar(int x)
{
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
{
    if(i<x)
    {
         return false;
         break;
    }
    //some operation 
}
```

Is this break statement necessary, considering the boolean function has already returned out of it by then

Comment: No, the `break` is unreachable.  You should have a warning.

Comment: I'd ask whoever told you it was a bad idea to return from the loop *why* they think it's a bad idea - and if they palm you off with "methods should only have one return point" ask them *why* methods should only have one return point. A lot of this sort of thing comes from people parroting patterns which were a best practice in other languages.

Comment: *I was recently told that it is a bad practice to return false from inside a loop* who told you so?

Comment: The only bad thing I see is the fact that you have unreachable code like @roryap pointed out. Also if you want some operation to be performed when i > x then in this case it wont be fired unless x = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Break statement is **unnecessary**

Here's why

**IL code** for **foo()**

```
bool flag = this.bar();
if (flag)
{
    // some commented code
}
```

and in **IL code** for **bar()** below

Notice the there is no

> break;

after the line

> **return result;**

```
private bool bar()
{
    bool result;
    int num;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = num + 1)
    {
        bool flag = i < 1;
        if (flag)
        {
            result = false;
            return result;
        }
        num = i;
    }
    result = true;
    return result;
}
```

> break;

is actually removed by the C# compiler when compiling to IL Code

Answer (score -1):

Usually

`return` is indicator to exit the method and return the result.

`break` is used when you want to exit the loop, iterative processes.

i think it's not best approach, but you can do that, at least the compiler will know what to do however suggesting you the warning.

you should see the `break` warning